# How to bind visibiility and content of label based on validation done on the text entered by user in textbox?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding, routed-commands

I am writing simple application. The UI has two textboxes, for Username and Password, and button to submit the information. I wanted to use routed commands instead of buttonclick event.

Username should contain alphanumeric characters only, if user enter any other special characters, it should display a label saying invalid characters entered. So I wanted to bind the visibility and content of that label based on the validation done on Username textbox field.

Below is code I have made but it is not working as expected. Can any one help me where I am doing wrong?

Below my main Window

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.ComponentModel;


namespace ExcelUtility
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ViewModel viewModelObj = new ViewModel();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    void navigatePageExecuted(object target, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SubmitUserDetails(txtUserName.Text + ";" + txtPassword);
    }

    void navigatePageCanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
         if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtUserName.Text))
        {
            viewModelObj.Username = txtUserName.Text;
        }
        e.CanExecute = viewModelObj.VaidUserName;        }

    private void SubmitUserDetails(string credentials)
    {
        this.Cursor = Cursors.Wait;
        prgValidate.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        MainGrid.IsEnabled = false;
        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
        worker.RunWorkerAsync(credentials);
    }

    void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        prgValidate.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        string Result = (string)e.Result;
        MessageBox.Show(Result); //Here I need to call some other functions based on return value for simplicity i have changed
    }

    void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        string[] credentials = e.Argument.ToString().Split(';');
        e.Result = viewModelObj.validateCredentials(credentials[0], credentials[1]);
    }
}
}
```

This is my xaml

```
<Window x:Class="ExcelUtility.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ExcelUtility"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <local:BoolToVisibleOrHidden x:Key="BoolToVisibilityConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static local:CommandsLibrary.navigatePageCommand}" Executed="navigatePageExecuted" CanExecute="navigatePageCanExecute"/>
</Window.CommandBindings>
<Grid Name="MainGrid">
    <TextBlock Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="40,44,0,0" Name="tbUserName" Text="Username" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="136,42,0,0" Name="txtUserName" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="163" Text="{Binding Username, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    <TextBlock Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="138,19,0,0" Name="tbNotify" Text="{Binding Notification, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="161" Visibility="{Binding NotVaidUserName,Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" />
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="138,98,0,0" Name="txtPassword" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="161" />
    <TextBlock Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="44,107,0,0" Name="tbPassword" Text="Password" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="65" />
    <Button Command="{x:Static local:CommandsLibrary.navigatePageCommand}" Content="Submit" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="172,167,0,0" Name="btnSubmit" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="109" />
    <ProgressBar Height="24" IsIndeterminate="True" Visibility="Collapsed"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="52,232,0,0" Name="prgValidate" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="257" />
</Grid>
</Window>
```

This is my viewModel

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows;

namespace ExcelUtility
{
  public class ViewModel
  {
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private bool _notVaidUserName;
    public bool NotVaidUserName
    {
        get { return _notVaidUserName; }
        set
        {
            _notVaidUserName = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("NotVaidUserName");
        }
    }

    private string notification;
    public string Notification
    {
        get
        {
            return notification;
        }
        set
        {
            if (notification != value)
            {
                notification = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Notification");
            }
        }
    }

    private string username;
    public string Username
    {
        get
        {
            return username;
        }
        set
        {
            if (username != value)
            {
                username = value;
                NotVaidUserName = VaidateUserName(username);
                RaisePropertyChanged("Username");
            }
        }
    }

    public bool VaidateUserName(string strUsername)
    {
        bool bValidUserName = false;            
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strUsername))
        {
            if (new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$").IsMatch(strUsername))
            {
                bValidUserName = true;
                if (strUsername.Length > 7)
                {
                    Notification = "Max allowed key length is 6";
                    bValidUserName = false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Notification = "No special characters allowed";
            }
        }
        return bValidUserName;
    }

    public string validateCredentials(string Username, string Password)
    {
        return "Valid Credentials";
    }

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

class BoolToVisibleOrHidden : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        object returnvalue = new object();
        returnvalue = (bool)value ? Visibility.Visible : parameter != null ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Hidden;
        return returnvalue;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (Visibility)value == Visibility.Visible;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First define two properties like below:

```
private bool isValid = true;
    public bool IsValid
    {
        get
        {
            return isValid;
        }
        set
        {
            if (isValid != value)
            {
                isValid = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsValid");
            }
        }
    }
    private string username;
    public string Username
    {
        get
        {
            return username;
        }
        set
        {
            if(username != value)
            {
                username = value;
                IsValid = ValidateForSpecialCharacters(username);
                OnPropertyChanged("Username");
            }
        }
    }
```

Then bind them to your xaml like this:

```
    <TextBlock Text="Username contains special characters."
               Visibility="{Binding IsValid,Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Username, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

PS: Don't forget to implement BoolToVisibility converter class and ValidateForSpecialCharacter method. I think you can handle it on your own. By the way, if I were you, I would use [ValidationRule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753962(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of this way.

Hope this help.

Comment: Hi,Thanks a lot for your reply. I have tried as you have mentioned. but it is not working as expected. I have posted my code can you please let me know where I am doing wrong.
can you please also let me know how to do control template validation. thanks much

Answer (score 0):

You must create a boolToVis converter, which convert False to collapsed and True to visible.

After this, you can bind the bool value to the visibility property of your item.

This is the converter (you can put this in a single file and call it from xaml):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace yourNamespace.ViewModel
{
    [ValueConversion(typeof(bool), typeof(bool))]
    public class InverseBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,  
           System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value is bool)
            {
                return !(bool)value;
            }
            return value;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,  
           System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value is bool)
            {
                return !(bool)value;
            }
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

then, from your xaml, at the the beginning of the file:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVis"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

or if you use a window:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVis"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

then, finally, in your textBox:

```
<dxe:TextEdit Visibility="{Binding YOURBOOLFLAG, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}" EditValue="TextHere"/>
```

(TextEdit is a devexpress element; you can also use the classic textBox in the same way)

in this way, when you see that the text is not correct for you, you can set the bool flag to false and hide the element.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply implement a converter that check the username character like so:

```
class VisibilityConverter:IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var rgx = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$");
        if (value == null) return Visibility.Hidden;
        return (rgx.IsMatch(value.ToString()))?Visibility.Hidden:Visibility.Visible;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

don't forget to add the converter to the window resources

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <conv:VisibilityConverter x:Key="VisibilityConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

and finally use that converter in your UI to check the string entered in the textBox

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="Username" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Password" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"/>   
    <TextBox  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Username,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    <TextBox  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Password,Mode=TwoWay}"/>      
    <Button Content="login" IsEnabled="{Binding Username,Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter},Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="invalid characters entered"  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Visibility="{Binding Username,Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}"></TextBlock>

</Grid>
```

Comment: Hi I have tried as you have mentioned, but I could not achieve what you said. I have placed my code now. can you please help me where I am doing wrong?